# Why my path of swf file( in my case flip book) won't display?

Tags: html, wordpress, flash, adobe, swfobject

I have a problem! I want to set a path of a flip book, to use in wordpress. I set the path of a two flipbooks. One of them is working, and one of them not. 
I set the same path, the only difference is the number of pages(108/180). I have no idea, why larger file is not working. I already tried to set all permission of an adobe programe in case that this was a problem, but without success.

Maybe this is a stupid question, but it's driving me crazy!

I set a path from server ftp(In local host it's working)

**Path**: domain-name/wp-content/themes/theme-name/name-of-folder/name-of-file.html

[Flipbook-current status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqXLN.png)

- Screenshot, what I get(It looks like it's loading, but it's not)

Thank you